# Stack a square DataFrame to only keep the upper/lower triangle

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a symmetric square `DataFrame` in `pandas`:

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 3)
a = (a + a.T)/2
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1.)
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

That looks like this:

```
          0         1         2
0  1.000000  0.747064  0.357616
1  0.747064  1.000000  0.631622
2  0.357616  0.631622  1.000000
```

If I apply the `stack` method, I would get lots of redundant information (including the diagonal, in which I'm not interested):

```
0  0    1.000000
   1    0.747064
   2    0.357616
1  0    0.747064
   1    1.000000
   2    0.631622
2  0    0.357616
   1    0.631622
   2    1.000000
```

Is there a way to only get the lower (or upper) triangle this using "pure" `pandas`?

```
1  0    0.747064
2  0    0.357616
   1    0.631622
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `mask`

```
In [278]: a.mask(np.triu(np.ones(a.shape)).astype(bool)).stack()
Out[278]:
1  0    0.747064
2  0    0.357616
   1    0.631622
dtype: float64
```

Or use `where`

```
In [285]: a.where(np.tril(np.ones(a.shape), -1).astype(bool)).stack()
Out[285]:
1  0    0.747064
2  0    0.357616
   1    0.631622
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I could think of is to force the upper (or lower) triangle to NaN, as by default the `stack` method will not include NaNs:

```
a.values[np.triu_indices_from(a, 0)] = np.nan
a.stack()
```

which gives:

```
1  0    0.747064
2  0    0.357616
   1    0.631622
```